# How to improve user experience in mobile/responsive screen when we deal with complex table structure?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, experience

How to design complex table structure in responsive screen (mobile)?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcwa0F.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Above is the table structure. Each cell in the table can 'n' no.of data. How can we make this layout responsive in mobile without disturbing the user experience.

On click of numerical **+5** it will expand in same cell.

Is there any alternate solution for this kind of view?

Comment: Why is table Essential? What are the reasons for choosing this metaphor even on desktop? What is the correlation between things?

Comment: @Harshal what is the alternative for table?

Answer (score 5):

The typical alternative on mobile would be to stack it in to one column and use cards for each area. Something like this:

[image]