# How to design for a very complex table on mobile?

Tags: mobile, tables

I've searched all over, seen some examples, but none of them are barely close to my challenge. See image attatched.

[image]

Obviously locking a column won't work. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Hi @feelerino, just closing this question because we have had similar questions and it is easier to keep all the answers in one discussion thread (unless you think there is something unique about your situation). Also another similar question you can reference: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/107104/how-to-improve-user-experience-in-mobile-responsive-screen-when-we-deal-with-com

Answer (score 2):

I had a Similar challenge at work, but instead of fitting the table in the small screen, we rearranged the information to create a list. Here is an example of something you could do:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was doing some research on this some time ago. One example that I found is to show one column (or a couple if it fits) at a time and provide a way to navigate to the other columns. One basic example can be found here: https://daverupert.com/2016/05/responsive-comparison-tables/

You may be able to fit the Disciplina and 1 periodo columns in the view and have a nav element to jump to the other periodo.